# Choose entities from data-frame where dummy-variable is 1 at least once

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data-frame:

```
df=data.frame(student=c(rep("John",6),rep("Meredith",7),rep("Jeremy",5),rep("Audrey",8)),
               semester=c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, 1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
               addQual=c( 1,0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,1,0,1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

It contains students, all their semesters and for every semester whether they took an additional qualifications course(dummy variable addQual = 1 if they took it).
How can I get a data-frame dfFilt that only contains those students who ever participated in an additional qualifications course?

My desired output would therefore be:

```
dfFilt=data.frame(student=c(rep("John",6),rep("Jeremy",5)),
               semester=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,  1,2,3,4,5),
               addQual=c( 1,0,0,0,1,0,  0,0,1,0,1))
```

A solution in dplyr is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr`:

```
dfFilt = df %>% group_by(student) %>% filter(sum(addQual)>=1)

   student semester addQual
    <fctr>    <dbl>   <dbl>
 1    John        1       1
 2    John        2       0
 3    John        3       0
 4    John        4       0
 5    John        5       1
 6    John        6       0
 7  Jeremy        1       0
 8  Jeremy        2       0
 9  Jeremy        3       1
10  Jeremy        4       0
11  Jeremy        5       1
```

Comment: thanks! that I didn't come up with this... now that I see it, a little addition to this for future visiters: `%>% filter(any(addQual==1))` would work as well

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution

```
df[which(df$student %in% df$student[which(df$addQual >0)]), ]
   student semester addQual
1     John        1       1
2     John        2       0
3     John        3       0
4     John        4       0
5     John        5       1
6     John        6       0
14  Jeremy        1       0
15  Jeremy        2       0
16  Jeremy        3       1
17  Jeremy        4       0
18  Jeremy        5       1
```